# Office 365 requires an online repair every reboot

Tags: windows-8.1, office365

[image: when attempting to quick repair] - Quick Repair failure

Initially when I first installed it on a fresh windows 8.1 install, it worked just fine every reboot. Then nothing happened aside from one additional reboot months down the road. Now every reboot necessitates an online repair which takes an obnoxious amount of time on my slow work connection as it re-downloads the entire program.

Is there anything that can be done aside from 1) wiping office completely and installing again [doesn't help] and 2) wiping windows completely and installing again [please no]. Quick repairs don't work at all post-reboot.

This software is terrible but I'm forced to use it so no alternatives are possible.

I've also tried doing a quick repair and online repair *before* I reboot - doesn't matter.

My configuration is pretty much as basic as it gets. One admin user account. All drivers are up to date; Windows is up to date. No other weird problems. Operation is butter smooth except this terrible software package.

---

Update:

I used the MS provided complete removal FixIt yet the problem remains the same. This is a rampant issue from what I can tell - tons of other users are reporting the same thing. (By that I mean the FixIt not actually Fix*ing*It)

Update 2:

Signing out and signing back in does not cause the failure to occur. Switching from x64 to x86 makes no difference.

Update 3:

Thinking it might be much less of a PITA to repair only the OneDrive business application, I went about setting up Thunderbird in place of outlook using an EWS URL for calendar and suffice it to say, it takes equally as long to set up/repair a single tiny app as compared to the whole suite. I guess it's all bundled together regardless, except it did in fact only install the OneDriveB after about 30+ minutes. This is just the worst implementation I've ever seen.

Comment: First you should really be told that reinstalling Windows won't solve this problem.

Comment: I understand it is a last resort that may only temporarily fix the inherent problem.

Comment: No; I won't solve the problem;  The only reason it would work is because you would have to install Office 365 again.

Comment: In the past I had O365 installed on a windows 7 machine. No matter how many times I installed/uninstalled the software, there was something fundamentally wrong with the base (windows 7) that prevented it from working properly.

Comment: I have installed O365 on over 1,000 windows 7 machines and I can tell you there is nothing fundamentally wrong with windows 7 that prevents O365. What kind of business model would that be?! What is the issue with uninstalling O365 completely and reinstalling?

Comment: I didn't mean windows 7 in general, just the particular install that I had. It's a pain, takes hours, and sometimes muddles up the system even further. It's an obvious route so I just wanted to see if there was anything else prior to embarking down that path.

Comment: @Wutnaut: Uninstalled it completely and reinstalled - no better off.

Comment: If you installed Office (the non-online version) then see [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_resource_kit/archive/2013/06/17/automating-quick-repairs-in-office-365-proplus.aspx). One [Office 365 article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg998767%28v=office.15%29.aspx#BKMK_OfficeRepair) says the cause for this error is system services which are not running - do you see any services that were installed with Office 365?

Comment: @harrymc: 'Microsoft Office ClickToRun Service' is running in automatic. 'Office 64 Source Engine' is not running and set to manual. Those are the only two that stand out. That first link is a command line alternative for something I tried and doesn't work. The second, as far as I can tell just says to do an online repair to fix the problem of needing a repair without saying what services may need to be running to prevent it in the first place... facepalm.

Comment: I haven't found either any documentation about such services. You might try to set the Source Engine service to automatic and reboot. Have a good look at any other services that seem connected to Office. BTW, do you have installed the non-online version of Office, and which one?

Comment: @harrymc: Ya that is worth a try. I only have the online office 365 software installed.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the automatic updates.
File-> Office Account-> Update Options-> Disable Updates

Comment: Yes. That is not the issue. I can reboot back to back and will still need a repair every time even when there were no updates.

Comment: Any news about system services?

Comment: No luck. Enabling that additional service (automatic and start before reboot) resulted in the same thing. I updated the question with an image of the error from a quick repair.

Comment: Now, after setting that service to automatic, the online repair failed and removed office. I'll have to completely uninstall and install it again.

Comment: Might be a good idea. Use an uninstaller like [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) to completely uninstall it.

Comment: Thinking it might be much less of a PITA to repair only the OneDrive business application, I went about setting up Thunderbird in place of outlook using an EWS URL for calendar and suffice it to say, it takes equally as long to set up/repair a single tiny app as compared to the whole suite. I guess it's all bundled together regardless, except it did in fact only install the OneDriveB after about 30 minutes. This is just the worst implementation I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resolve these by error fixing tool only, as i too went with the same issues before you. then i got a link from microsoft site.
Try the steps below and check the result:

Since repair failed to fix the issue, I would suggest you to run the fix it mentioned in the link below to remove the traces of Office completely from the computer and then reinstall the Office program, check if it helps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501

its worked to me......hope you too clear your issues.

Comment: The FixIt itself was no help but it removed most of what the manual guide had me remove. I went a little further and did a partial purge of anything relating to 'office' in the registry, program files, and programdata. I also had a start-up entry that was launching groove.exe directly and I think this was the main cause of the problem.